# Question similar to Collatz game

Tags: number-theory

A problem is this:

Something I'm thinking about. 
Let $f(n)$ be the number of $1$ bits in $n$, i.e 
$f(3)=2,f(8)=1$
consider the trajectory of a natural $k$ under the map $n -> n+f(n)$. does it always collapse into the trajectory of $1$ under the same map?

PLEASE Help!!!
do you need to use Turán's theorem??

the first $30$ numbers when doing this game starting from $1$ is

```
2 3 5 7 10 12 14 17 19 22 25 28 31 36 38 41 44 47 52 55 60 64 65 67 70 73 76 79 84 87
```

and then if we start from $4$, we get

```
5 7 10 12 14 17 19 22 25 28 31 36 38 41 44 47 52 55 60 64 65 67 70 73 76 79 84 87 92 96
```

and if we start from $6$ we get:

```
8 9 11 14 17 19 22 25 28 31 36 38 41 44 47 52 55 60 64 65 67 70 73 76 79 84 87 92 96 98
```

and if we start from $11$, we get

```
14 17 19 22 25 28 31 36 38 41 44 47 52 55 60 64 65 67 70 73 76 79 84 87 92 96 98 101 105 109
```

and if we start from $13$ we get

```
16 17 19 22 25 28 31 36 38 41 44 47 52 55 60 64 65 67 70 73 76 79 84 87 92 96 98 101 105 109
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OEIS sequence [A096303](https://oeis.org/A096303) is related to this question.

The author *conjectures* that any number will meet the trajectory of 1 under the map $n \rightarrow n + f(n)$.